# Selenium multiple wait conditions fail

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, implicitwait

The following code is not working. The selenium web driver just continues through without waiting even though neither of the elements are visible on the page. Therefore the assertion fails.

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            lambda x: (EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "export_errors_button"))) or
                      (EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "finish_button")))
        )
assert "finish_button" in element.get_attribute('id').split()
```

Comment: it means that your ids are actually present on the page, therefore it does not wait, there is no such thing as a pause, the use of thread.sleep is not recommended, so a little trick i use is actually wait for an element that does not exist and catch the exception

Comment: Could you elaborate please. Also I'm checking for their visibility, not their existence.

Comment: `EC.presence_of_element_located()` produces same result ?

Comment: Are the visible in HTML DOM ? Selenium interacts with HTMLDOM not what you see in the UI.

Comment: EC.presence_of_element_located() produces the same result. Both elements are set to style="display:none".

Comment: Its something to do with the lambda function. Both functions work on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom wait condition.

```
def one_of_these_elements_is_visible(element1, element2):
    def wait_for_condition(driver):
        attribute = driver.find_element(By.ID, element1).is_displayed()
        if attribute:
            return True
        else:
            return driver.find_element(By.ID, element2).is_displayed()
    return wait_for_condition


element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(one_of_these_elements_is_visible("finish_button",
                                                                              "export_errors_button"))
```